# How to check right operand for functions return by reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Say I'm implementing an element-access operator[] to access individual element from a customized vector class. Something like this:

```
vector A;
int a = A[2]; // access the 3rd element
```

Since the implementation of operator[] is generally return by reference, it can be chained to do the following operation as well

```
A[2] = 7;
```

My question is that, in the second usage A[2] = 7,  is there a way to check the right operand, namely 7 in this example. I want this feature as, in some occasions, the vector class will be a binary vector, hence one can only assign 0 or 1 to it. I'd like to check the right operand to make sure that assignment of any number other than 0/1 is forbidden. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to use only `0` and `1` then why not to use `enum class`?

Comment: Generally it's not possible, but you can work around that by returning a proxy object with an assignment operator.

Comment: Yola, I implemented class 'vector' as a templated class and binary vector is only a special case. Therefore, I use templated specialization to redefined everything for binary vector. In other words, class 'vector' is not a standalone class, I wonder if your suggestion of enum class can still work in this case.

Comment: I believe yes, that's a good way to go for you. `enum class E { ... }; template <> struct A<E> { ... };`

Comment: So basically, you create an enum class E first, then use E to specialize the generic template. Brilliant. If I haven't started this project, I would definitely try your approach.  But, 90% of the codes are finished now and your proposal incurs too much modification of existing codes. Anyway, lesson learnt. Thank you.

Comment: Even though you have already accepted an answer, I believe your problem definition is vague. You said, "I want this feature as, in some occasions, the vector class will be a binary vector*. What is "in some occasions"? How do you make that determination? Is there some flag in the container that indicates that you should accept only binary values?

Comment: R Sahu, yes there is some flag to indicate this. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider two ways.

The first one is to use proxy object like this

```
class vector {
    std::vector<int> _v;

public:
    vector(int i) : _v(i) {}

    class Proxy {
        int &_i;
    public:
        Proxy(int& i) : _i(i) {}
        Proxy& operator=(int i) { if (i != 1) throw; _i = i; return *this; }
        operator int() { return _i; }
    };

    Proxy operator[](int i) { return Proxy(_v[i]); }
};

int main()
{
    vector v(5);
    v[1] = 1; // ok
    v[2] = 2; // throw
}
```

The second one is to use either `enum class` or your class which accepts only 0 and 1 instead of `int`. This option might be better here as it conveys semantics to the user, while using int doesn't say casual reader that 0 and 1 is the only acceptable values.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a helper class for this purpose, which overloads the assigning operator (`operator=`). The array subscript operator returns an object of the helper class instead of an array element. Assigning a value to this object calls the assigning operator which implements the checks an assigns the value if necessary.

Something like this:

```
class vector {
    struct bucket {
        private int &_element;
        bucket(int &inElement): _element(inElement) {
        }
        int &operator=(int inValue) {
            // Do your checks here
            _element = inValue;
            return _element;
        }
    }
    bucket operator[](int i) {
        return bucket(_elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Note that this is no running code. It's just for demonstrating the concept.